# Conan boost 1.71.0 missing dependencies

Tags: c++, boost, conan

I am working on a project and I have to use boost and conan to manage my packages.
I use the last version on conan center.

> boost/1.71.0@conan/stable

On windows I don't have any trouble but on linux, conan doesn't install all the boost dependencies.
For exemple on Linux `boost_property_tree` is missing. I have to use `boost_property_tree/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable` but it's still missing something. In my case `boost/mpl/void_fwd.hpp` is missing so I had to add `boost_mpl/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable` but it's still missing.

Someone now why boost is correctly setup on windows but not on linux ?

Comment: Please don't use anymore the ``boost/1.71.0@conan/stable`` dependencies. They are old. The new ones don't have the "user/channel" part, so something like ``boost/1.71.0`` is what you should be using. Now open source packages in ConanCenter are generated from an automatic build service from the https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repo.

Comment: But boost_property_tree is still missing with your way.

Comment: The modular boost is not included in ConanCenter, and at least at the moment, the monolithic one from ConanCenter is recommended (this is still the official way that Boost is released). Conan is learning "components" that will let to link with the components you want from the monolithic package, but it is possible that using the modular, splitted libs like ``boost_property_tree`` is not necessary for your use case.